# Precedence of alternation vs sequencing in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I believed that sequencing (implicitly given by order of subrules) had a higher priority in ANTLR4 parser than alternation (explictly given by | character), meaning that

`a : x | y z ;`

was semantically identical to

`a : x | ( y z) ;`

Looking in the ANTLR4 book and searching generally I can't find a clear statement of this but it seems reasonable, however given a rule

```
expression :
        pmqident
    |
        constant 
    | 
[snip]
    | 
        '(' scalar_subquery ')' 
    |
        unary_operator expression   // this is unbracketed
    |
        expression binary_operator expression
[snip]
    ;
```

and I feed it this `select - 2 / 3` I get this parse tree

[image: parse tree of unbracketed expression]

whereas if I just add brackets around `unary_operator expression` and change absolutely nothing else, to get this

```
expression :
[snip]
        '(' scalar_subquery ')' 
    |
        ( unary_operator expression )   // brackets added here
    |
        expression binary_operator expression
[snip]
    ;
```

and give it the same SQL, I get this

[image: parse tree of bracketed expression]

What am I misunderstanding?

(BTW and separately, the freaky parse of "- 2 / 3" into "(- ( 2 / 3))" is actually the one I want. That's how MSSQL does it. Mad world)

### ------

Ok, to reproduce (works for me), not utterly minimal but heavily stripped code. File is named MSSQL.g4:

```
grammar MSSQL;

expression :
        constant 
    |
        unary_operator expression  // bracket/unbracket this
    |
        expression binary_operator expression  
    ;

constant : INTEGER_CONST ;

INTEGER_CONST : [0-9]+ ;

binary_operator :
        arithmetic_operator
    ;

arithmetic_operator :
        subtract
    |
        divide
    ;

add_symbol : PLUS_SIGN ;
subtract   : MINUS_SIGN ;
divide     : DIVIDE_SIGN ;

unary_operator :
        SIGN
    ;

SIGN : PLUS_SIGN | MINUS_SIGN ;

DIVIDE_SIGN : '/' ;
PLUS_SIGN  : '+' ;
MINUS_SIGN : '-' ;

SKIPWS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

The DOS crud to compile it (relevant parts given):

```
set CurrDir=%~dp0
set CurrDir=%CurrDir:~0,-1%
cd %CurrDir%

java  org.antlr.v4.Tool  -Werror  -o %CurrDir%\MSSQL  MSSQL.g4
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto problem

javac  %CurrDir%\MSSQL\MSSQL*.java
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto problem

cd ./MSSQL
echo enter sql...
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig MSSQL expression -gui -trace  -tokens
```

input is `- 2 / 3`

Running on win2k8R2, versions of bits are as follows

```
C:\Users\jan>java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\jan>java  org.antlr.v4.Tool
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.5.1
```

Anything else needed? Can anyone reproduce?

Frankly I'm struggling to believe this is a bug. It's just too elemental.

FYI I found this originally not by bracketing/unbracketing but by hoisting the body of a subrule into rule, and noticed behaviour changed.

Comment: Post a reproducible example grammar.

Comment: This is not a Q about the grammar but about my understanding - _have I misunderstood antlr?_ If I have, the grammar's not the problem, otherwise I can start digging before posting again here - on past performance, it's probably something foolish I've done.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't make a difference if you add parentheses or not. The OR operator has the lowest precedence as you can see in the ANTLR 4 grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4#L299.

Comment: Has anyone been able to reproduce?

Comment: The behavior is a side effect of a known bug: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/564

Comment: @GRosenberg: was about to question your creds but can see your name in the antlr4 commits. Ok. It's a pretty serious bug - spurious error msgs ok but different behaviour?? -  is I think not restricted to bracketing, as I said "FYI I found this originally not by bracketing/unbracketing but by hoisting the body of a subrule into rule" and was slated to have been fixed last year. Would adding brackets automatically around each arm of the alternative fix it? This is concerning.

Comment: @user3779002, are you working on MYSQL grammar? Sorry for offtopic.

Comment: Nah, MS SQL (why'd you ask?). FYI It allows some very odd things, has the strong smell of handwritten and not too competently at that.

Comment: @user3779002, sorry I mean exactly MS SQL :) I'am working on MS SQL grammar (TSQL) at present time. I'am getting syntax from msdn.

Comment: @KvanTTT: Am hoping to release mine open source. Also I know MSSQL and many of its warts, and know that BOL BNF is incomplete and sometimes plain wrong. If you want to combine, how to contact you?

Comment: @user3779002, let's do it together :) Please, write me email: kvanttt@gmail.com. I'am gonna upload my TSQL grammar to official ANTLR grammars repo later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is being written in the context of [antlr/antlr4#564](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/564) not being fixed.

During the code generation process, ANTLR looks for a few specific patterns when rewriting left-recursive rules to work in a recursive-descent parser.

Consider the following rule:

```
expression
  : INT
  | '++' expression
  | expression '++'
  | expression '+' expression
  ;
```

1. **Suffix:** Top-level alternatives which *start* with a recursive invocation. In the example, the alternative `expression '++'` falls into this category.
2. **Prefix:** Top-level alternatives which *end* with a recursive invocation. In the example, the alternative `'++' expression` falls into this category.
3. **Binary:** Top-level alternatives which *start and end* with a recursive invocation. In the example, the alternative `expression '+' expression` falls into this category.
4. **Other:** Everything else. In the example, the alternative `INT` falls into this category.

When matching these patterns, no simplifications are performed. This includes removing otherwise-unnecessary parentheses, which is the basis of issue [antlr/antlr4#564](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/564).

By including parentheses around a top-level alternative in a left-recursive rule, you force the alternative to be treated as **Other**. For alternatives that would normally be **Suffix** or **Binary**, this results in a compilation error due to left recursion that was not eliminated. For **Prefix** alternatives (which you have), the grammar still compiles but changes behavior because the alternative is treated as a primary expression instead of an operator which overrides its original position in the operator precedence sequence.

Note that including parentheses around a top-level alternative which was already in the **Other** category will not change behavior at all. Likewise, including parentheses around an alternative in a rule which is not left-recursive will not change behavior.